# Where or how can I watch "Heidi: Girl of the Alps"?

Tags: heidi-girl-of-the-alps

Does anybody know how or where I can watch the anime "Heidi: Girl of the Alps" *legally*? I remember watching this as a kid, and loving it, but I am unable to find any links to it now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Heidi-Girl-Alps-remastered-DVD-BOX/dp/B003WJD9XQ
There's your answer. I will not tell you how to watch it illegally. If you haven't figured out how by now, you really needn't be doing it. Just buy the dvd set.

Comment: Outside of ordering online (or CD/DVD shops wherever you live), I'm not sure whether there's a short answer for this. A lot of online streaming is region-specific, and even the viability of ordering online depends on your location.

Comment: Your name suggests that this isn’t an option, but it frequently airs in German children’s television (yes, even nowadays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now there is no legal online source where you can watch Heidi girl of the alps.

Your best bet would be to buy [the dvd box](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003WJD9XQ) like Alex-sama mentioned in his comment.

Comment: The Crunchyroll page says "Note: There are no videos for this Series. This page is only for discussion and informational purposes." so I don't think you can actually watch this there.

Comment: This answer lacks research, if the comment by Logan M is true. Can't confirm from work, Crunchyroll is blocked.

Comment: @LoganM Guess I skipped over the site to rashly during lunch, Indeed discussion only. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently available with the Filmbox addon for Amazon Prime.  Though, I'm not sure which countries it's available in, as I can only check for the United States. I'm also not sure if it's available in via Filmbox separatly from Amazon Prime.  Here is the Amazon Prime page for it: https://www.amazon.com/gp/video/detail/amzn1.dv.gti.8b3a9fa8-e146-42cf-afbb-c239775b83a4

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, this is such a classic, old-school anime that my mother adored and could not find any legal streaming sites that broadcasts it, as far as the ones that I know of.

There's a brief mention of a VHS English dub release on Wikipedia and ANN database, but I haven't came across it or heard of a current DVD distribution.